# Какой сервис прогноза погоды лучше всего использовать в своем веб-приложении?

Tags: php

Вопрос такой - какой сервис прогноза погоды лучше всего использовать в своем веб-приложении? Нужен сервис с API.

Comment: У gismeteo есть настраиваемые информеры [http://www.gismeteo.ru/informers/](http://www.gismeteo.ru/informers/)

Comment: Информер погоды это не совсем не то, что мне нужно, но все равно спасибо за помощь.